# Get max of timestamp from list of dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe table like below

```
status    time&status

recived    [{'status':'pending','date':'21-09-2010'},{'status':'recived','date':'21-10-2011'}]
recived    [{'status':'recived','date':'21-10-2011'}]
pending    [{'status':'pending','date':'19-09-2009'},{'status':'recived','date':'21-10-2001'}]
recived    [{'status':'pending','date':'21-09-2010'},{'status':'recived','date':'21-10-2011'}]
```

I want to find the maximum of date in the list of dictionaries in time&status column. Like below in the form of list.
The new list should have `['21-10-2011','21-10-2011','19-09-2009','21-10-2011']`

I tried the below code for the complete column but it didn't help and throwing `string indices must be integers`

```
new_list=[]
for i in new['time&status']:
    new_list.append(max([x['date'] for x in i]))
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First necessary convert values to dictionaries and then use your solution in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with convert values to datetimes:

```
import ast
df['time&status'] = df['time&status'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

f = lambda x: max(pd.to_datetime([y['date'] for y in x], format='%d-%m-%Y'))
df['new'] = df['time&status'].apply(f)
print (df)
     status                                        time&status        new
0  recived  [{'status': 'pending', 'date': '21-09-2010'}, ... 2011-10-21
1  recived      [{'status': 'recived', 'date': '21-10-2011'}] 2011-10-21
2  pending  [{'status': 'pending', 'date': '19-09-2009'}, ... 2009-09-19
3  recived  [{'status': 'pending', 'date': '21-09-2010'}, ... 2011-10-21
```

If need original format:

```
f = lambda x: max(pd.to_datetime([y['date'] for y in x], format='%d-%m-%Y'))
df['new'] = df['time&status'].apply(f).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
print (df)
     status                                        time&status         new
0  recived  [{'status': 'pending', 'date': '21-09-2010'}, ...  21-10-2011
1  recived      [{'status': 'recived', 'date': '21-10-2011'}]  21-10-2011
2  pending  [{'status': 'pending', 'date': '19-09-2009'}, ...  19-09-2009
3  recived  [{'status': 'pending', 'date': '21-09-2010'}, ...  21-10-2011
```